# What are the limitations or point to be remembererd while sharing objects with master detail relationship between to salesforce orgs

Tags: master-detail, salesforce2salesforce

I have 2 orgs which are connected through salesforce to salesforce connection.
I updated the lookups to master detail and now the objects are not getting shared.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the below link it may help you.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce

And also one key point to remember is that you should not use two look up fields referencing the same object like if you have an opportunity object, you already have look up to populate Account Name, So in case if you have a custom field in opportunity referencing the Account object again, Then records will not be shared. Thats the limitation.

Comment: Thanks..!!! All the S2S settings are already done and the objects were shared before I updated the objects to master detail. Again if I go back and change the relationship to lookup, the objects get shared. Not sure of the reason why this behaviour.

Comment: I was able to figure out the reason and this was happening since the Auto accept option was not checked for child objects. Still I have a doubt whether the child objects can be accepted automatically or not?